# Only use text-indent on wrapped lines

Tags: html, css

How can I apply the text-indent only to lines that are wrapped (have a line break)?

Right now, it looks like this:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

Is that possible using CSS 3? My `text-indent` is set to `text-indent: 20px`

Comment: These two are different paragraphs right? You can set the text indent using span or by making them as different paragraph tags.

Comment: Yes, good point but I hoped to be able to achieve this using only CSS

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible, there is property in css3 `::first-line`  but following properties can be used with ::first-line

```
font properties
color properties 
background properties
word-spacing
letter-spacing
text-decoration
vertical-align
text-transform
line-height
clear
```

and this is not for **text -indent**
 You can add another class or tag or span for each multiple line text **OR** use [Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/jgey1aqf/1/)